# LeetCodeにおける入出力について

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

コーディング問題サイト`LeetCode`の[AddBinary](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/)

という問題を解き、ローカル環境ではテストケースの正しい答えを得ることができたのですが、LeetCodeのWebサイトで実行（Run Codeボタンをクリック）すると以下のエラーが起きてしまいます。

LeetCodeに合わせた入出力条件にするためには、コードをどのように改変するべきでしょうか。

[image: Run Code Result]

実行したコード

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.num1 = a
        self.num2 = b

    def addBinary(self):
        result = int(self.num1, 2) + int(self.num2, 2)
        result = bin(result)
        result = str(result)
        result = result[2:]
        print(result)

#テストケース例
#trial = Solution("1010", "1011")
#trial.addBinary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リンク先に初めてアクセスすると以下のようなテンプレが表示されます。

```
class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a: str, b: str) -> str:
```

このテンプレ通り(クラス`Solution`に2つの文字列型の引数を取り、結果として文字列型の値を返すメソッド`addBinary`を定義する)にしないといけないのではないですか?

```
class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a: str, b: str) -> str:
        result = int(a, 2) + int(b, 2)
        result = bin(result)
        result = result[2:]
        return result
```

ちなみに`bin`関数の戻り値は文字列ですから、`result = str(result)`は要らないですね。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございました。